# How to enforce JSON encoding for Phoenix Request?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

There's some API made with Phoenix, the API works with JSON.

But, when you test it and sent JSON with `curl` it fail because Phoenix doesn't parse the request as JSON. You need to explicitly add `application/json` header to `curl`. I'd like to make it more robust and tell Phoenix to always parse all requests as JSON.

Is there a way to force Phoenix to always treat requests as JSON and parse it as JSON?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use plug to set request headers as @AbM suggested, with the following code in Router:

```
def set_format conn, format do Plug.Conn.put_private conn, :phoenix_format, format end

def put_req_header conn, {key, value} do Plug.Conn.put_req_header conn, key, value end

pipeline :api do
  plug :put_req_header, {"accept", "application/json"}
  plug :put_req_header, {"content-type", "application/json"}
  plug :set_format, "json"
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
end
```

The request has been made with CURL

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4000/api/upload -d '{"key": "value"}'
```

The connection looks like:

```
%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{},
 before_send: [#Function<1.93474994/1 in Plug.Logger.call/2>,
  #Function<0.119481890/1 in Phoenix.LiveReloader.before_send_inject_reloader/1>],
 body_params: %{"{\"key\": \"value\"}" => nil},
 cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies}, halted: false,
 host: "localhost", method: "POST", owner: #PID<0.483.0>,
 params: %{"{\"key\": \"value\"}" => nil},
 path_info: ["api", "upload"], peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 58408},
 port: 4000,
 private: %{App.Router => {[], %{}},
   :phoenix_action => :upload,
   :phoenix_controller => ApiController, :phoenix_endpoint => App.Endpoint,
   :phoenix_format => "json", :phoenix_layout => {LayoutView, :app},
   :phoenix_pipelines => [:api],
   :phoenix_route => #Function<8.59735990/1 in App.Router.match_route/4>,
   :phoenix_router => App.Router, :phoenix_view => ApiView,
   :plug_session_fetch => #Function<1.89562996/1 in Plug.Session.fetch_session/1>},
 query_params: %{},
 query_string: "", remote_ip: {127, 0, 0, 1},
 req_cookies: %Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :cookies},
 req_headers: [{"user-agent", "curl/7.37.1"}, {"host", "localhost:4000"},
  {"accept", "application/json"}, {"content-length", "16"},
  {"content-type", "application/json"}],
 request_path: "/api/upload", resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{},
 resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"},
  {"x-request-id", "xxx"}], scheme: :http,
 script_name: [],
 secret_key_base: "xxx",
 state: :unset, status: nil}
```

It works if I add the `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` parameter to CURL, without it it doesn't work.

Comment: Would adding a plug in your router with [`put_req_header(conn, "accept", "application/json")`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_req_header/3) solve your issue?

Comment: Nope, it's not working :(

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. Maybe show your router.ex

Comment: @AbM thanks for the help, I updated the question and provided more details.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't works, maybe content parsing happens before the router...

Comment: You are right, `Plug.Parsers` is responsible for parsing the `params` and this is happening a few plugs before the router (check lib/<your_app>/enpoint.ex). I was able to set JSON as default however it was not pretty, so I won't share it

Comment: @AbM thank you, got it, yes it looks like it should be possible to fix it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If somebody will google for that and want to implement such behaviour.

`lib/%APP_NAME%/endpoint.ex`

```
 plug Plug.Head

 # add custom plug 
 plug :set_format, "json"
```

Define it:

```
  defp set_format(conn, format) do
    if Regex.match?(~r/^api.*/, conn.host) do
      Plug.Conn.put_private conn, :phoenix_format, format
    else
      conn
    end
  end
```

In this example we have dirty hack which will enforce JSON format for subdomain `api`

**It's not recommended** to do like that but since Phoenix enforcing HTML at any time this hack fix ridiculous behaviour like: Elixir.Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError for `pipeline :api` to show 404.json instead of 404.html

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `Phoenix.Controller.put_format/2` instead of `Plug.Conn.put_private/3`.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

Change `lib/%APP_NAME%/endpoint.ex`

```
...

plug Plug.RequestId
plug Plug.Telemetry, event_prefix: [:phoenix, :endpoint]

plug :set_header, {"accept", "application/json"}
plug :set_header, {"content-type", "application/json"}

...

plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
  pass: ["*/*"],
  json_decoder: Phoenix.json_library()

...

plug ExColeWeb.Router

defp set_header(conn, {header, value}) do
  Plug.Conn.put_req_header(conn, header, value)
end
```