# Force Phoenix to render JSON errors

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Running into a problem with Phoenix when a user attempts to hit an API route that doesn't exist. Phoenix appears to be looking to render "404.html" by default, resulting in a catch all render function being called (which returns a map) which then results in an error because Phoenix is attempting to render JSON as HTML.

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Phoenix.HTML.Safe.to_iodata/1 is undefined (module Phoenix.HTML.Safe is not available)
        Phoenix.HTML.Safe.to_iodata(%{error: %{errors: ["An internal error has occurred. Our team has been notified."], message: "Internal Error"}})
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:729: Phoenix.Controller.__put_render__/5
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:77: Phoenix.Endpoint.RenderErrors.instrument_render_and_send/5
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:62: Phoenix.Endpoint.RenderErrors.__catch__/5
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:42: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/4
```

This is the default render function that is ultimately being called:

```
  def render(code, _assigns) do
    Logger.error("Error handler requested #{inspect code}. Please add support for that.")

    %{
      error: %{
        message: "Internal Error",
        errors: ["An internal error has occurred. Out team has been notified."]
      }
    }
  end
```

I have seen "set_format" solution that was in a previous question (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189452) and, as the user states, this does feel a bit hacky, though it does appear to work.

I am also aware that I could just specify a render function that accepts 404.html but that also feels like a bit more of a bandaid than I would like.

My ultimate goal is to get Phoenix to not want to render 404.html, rather I would like to either arbitrarily specify the template, or at the least, tell Phoenix it should look for 404.json instead. Ideally, the solution would be application wide.

Answer (score 2):

Your router is just a plug. You can handle errors in the same way as `Plug.Router` or any plug does. In the sample code below, feel free to replace `MyAppWeb` with the name of your web module.

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Router do
  use MyAppWeb, :router
  use Plug.ErrorHandler  #<-- Add this line

  # and implement the callback handle_errors/2
  defp handle_errors(conn, %{reason: %Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError{message: message}}) do
    conn |> json(%{error: message}) |> halt()
  end

  defp handle_errors(conn, _) do
    conn |> json(%{error: "unknown"}) |> halt()
  end

  ...
end
```

Note that you can call all the functions that are available to a controller, because `Phoenix.Controller` is imported when you `import MyAppWeb, :router`. You can see this in the source code of the module `MyAppWeb`, pay attention to the macro `__using__/1` and the function `router/0`.

Comment: Makes sense, but I feel like this still isn't quite as elegant as I'd like. I guess I'm hoping for a configuration option that just tells Phoenix to always render JSON, or to give it a format to render like "#{error_name}.json". 

If this doesn't exist that is totally cool, just wanted to check. I do have a solution in place similar to what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your endpoint to render errors as json:

```
config :the_app, TheApp.Endpoint,
  render_errors: [view: TheApp.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(json), layout: false]
```